# Sorting and merging multiple linked lists with sorted sub-sections

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have an array of `numlists` linked lists. Nodes in the lists are of the form:

```
struct Edge
{
    int64_t blocknum;
    int64_t location;
    struct Edge *next;
};
typedef struct Edge edge;
```

I need to merge all the lists into a single linked list which is sorted by `location` in ascending order. Each list consists of blocks for which nodes have equal `blocknum`, and each of these blocks is already sorted. List blocks with larger values of `blocknum` have all of their location values larger than blocks with smaller `blocknum`. blocks in the sublists are already sorted in order of `blocknum` locally. Which means, practically, that this boils down to sorting blocks by `blocknum` in ascending order, and I don't have to worry too much about `location` since that will take care of itself. You may assume that the `next` member of an array is either valid and allocated, or explicitly declared NULL.

Here is the function I came up with

```
edge *sort_edges(edge **unsorted, int numlists)
{
    edge *sorted_head = NULL;
    edge *sorted_current = NULL;
    edge *current_edge = NULL;
    edge *temp = NULL;
    int64_t blocknum;

    int i;
    int64_t minblock;
    int remaining = numlists;
    int first = 1;
    int minblock_index;
    while(remaining) //while there are still more lists to process
    {
        minblock = LLONG_MAX;
        temp = NULL;
        minblock_index = INT_MAX;
        remaining = numlists;
        for (i=0; i<numlists; i++) //loop over the list of head nodes to find the one with the smallest blocknum
        {
            if (!unsorted[i]) //when a lists is exhausted the lead node becomes NULL, and we decrement the counter
            {
                remaining--;
            } 
            else //a simple minimum finding algorithm
            {
                current_edge = unsorted[i];
                if (current_edge->blocknum < minblock)
                {
                    temp = current_edge;
                    minblock = current_edge->blocknum;
                    minblock_index = i;
                }
            }
        }
        if (remaining == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (first) //if we have not yet set up the head of the list, we have to save a pointer to the head
        {
            sorted_head = temp;
            sorted_current = sorted_head;
            first = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            sorted_current->next = temp;
        }
        blocknum = sorted_current->blocknum;
        while (sorted_current->blocknum == blocknum && sorted_current->next) //skip through to the end of the block so that the next section we append will go on the end
        {
            sorted_current = sorted_current->next;
        }
        unsorted[minblock_index] = sorted_current->next; //reset the head of the unsorted list to the node after the block
    }
    return sorted_head;
}
```

This works. My question is:

Can I do better in terms of an efficient sorting algorithm? (Almost certainly yes, I'm just curious what people come up with for a sorting problem with the given assumptions).

Comment: Please note I edited the question since I found the original bug myself before anyone answered it. If anyone was typing a reply during that time let me know and I'll revert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "block" you mean the list hanging off from each pointer in the pointer array, then

```
int compare_edge_blocknum(const void *e1, const void *e2)
{
    if (!e1 && !e2)
        return 0;
    else
    if (!e1)
        return +1;
    else
    if (!e2)
        return -1;
    else {
        const int64_t b1 = ((edge *)e1)->blocknum;
        const int64_t b2 = ((edge *)e2)->blocknum;
        return (b1 < b2) ? -1 :
               (b1 > b2) ? +1 : 0;
    }
}

edge *last_in_list(edge *list)
{
    if (list)
        while (list->next)
            list = list->next;
    return list;
}

edge *sort_edges(edge **array, size_t count)
{
    edge   root = { 0, 0, NULL };
    edge  *tail = &root;
    size_t i;

    if (!array || count < 1)
        return NULL;
    if (count == 1)
        return array[0];

    qsort(array, count, sizeof *array, compare_edge_blocknum);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if (array[i]) {
            tail->next = array[i];
            tail = last_in_list(array[i]);
        }

    return root->next;
}
```

The above uses `qsort()` to sort the array of pointers, according to `blocknum`. We use `root` as a handle to the resulting list. We loop over the array of pointers, appending each non-NULL pointer to the `tail` of the result list, with `tail` always updated to point to the final element of the list.

Traversing each list to find the tail element is probably the slow part here, but unfortunately I don't see any way to avoid it. (If the list elements are not consecutive in memory, the list traversal tends to require many cache loads from RAM. The access patterns when the array is sorted are much easier for the CPU to predict (on current architectures), so the array sort part is probably not the slowest part -- but of course you can profile the code with a practical data set, and consider whether you need a faster sort implementation than the C library `qsort()`.)

---

OP clarified that each individual list hanging off a pointer in the pointer array may contain one or more "blocks", i.e. consecutive sorted runs. These can be detected by the changing blocknum.

If additional memory use is not an issue, I'd create an array of

```
typedef struct {
    int64_t  blocknum;
    edge    *head;
    edge    *tail;
} edge_block;
```

which then gets sorted by blocknum, and finally chained. Saving pointers to both the first (head) and last (tail) element means we only scan the lists once. After the edge_block array is sorted, a simple linear pass over it is enough to chain all the sublists into a final list.

For example (only compile-tested):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct Edge edge;
struct Edge {
    int64_t      blocknum;
    int64_t      location;
    struct Edge *next;
};

typedef struct {
    int64_t      blocknum;
    struct Edge *head;
    struct Edge *tail;
} edge_block;

static int cmp_edge_block(const void *ptr1, const void *ptr2)
{
    const int64_t b1 = ((const edge_block *)ptr1)->blocknum;
    const int64_t b2 = ((const edge_block *)ptr2)->blocknum;
    return (b1 < b2) ? -1 :
           (b1 > b2) ? +1 : 0;
}

edge *sort_edges(edge **array, size_t count)
{
    edge_block *block = NULL;
    size_t      blocks = 0;
    size_t      blocks_max = 0;
    edge       *root, *curr;
    size_t      i;

    if (count < 1) {
        errno = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!array) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        curr = array[i];

        while (curr) {

            if (blocks >= blocks_max) {
                edge_block *old = block;

                if (blocks < 512)
                    blocks_max = 1024;
                else
                if (blocks < 1048576)
                    blocks_max = ((blocks * 3 / 2) | 1023) + 1; 
                else
                    blocks_max = (blocks | 1048575) + 1048577;

                block = realloc(block, blocks_max * sizeof block[0]);
                if (!block) {
                    free(old);
                    errno = ENOMEM;
                    return NULL;
                }
            }

            block[blocks].blocknum = curr->blocknum;
            block[blocks].head = curr;

            while (curr->next && curr->next->blocknum == block[blocks].blocknum)
                curr = curr->next;

            block[blocks].tail = curr;
            blocks++;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }

    if (blocks < 1) {
        /* Note: block==NULL here, so no free(block) needed. */
        errno = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    qsort(block, blocks, sizeof block[0], cmp_edge_block);

    root = block[0].head;
    curr = block[0].tail;
    for (i = 1; i < blocks; i++) {
        curr->next = block[i].head;
        curr = block[i].tail;
    }

    free(block);

    errno = 0;
    return root;
}
```

---

If there are potentially very many blocknums, or you need to limit the amount of memory used, then I'd use a small min-heap of

```
typedef struct {
    size_t   count;
    edge    *head;
    edge    *tail;
} edge_block;
```

elements, keyed by `count`, the number of elements in that sublist.

The idea is that whenever you extract a block from the input, you add it to the min-heap if there is room; otherwise, you merge it with the root list in the min-heap. Note that according to OP's rules, this "merging" is actually a single insert, as each block is consecutive; only the insertion point needs to be found first. The `count` is updated to reflect the number of elements in the root list, and thus you re-heapify the min-heap.

The purpose of the heap is to ensure that you merge the two shortest blocks, keeping the traversal of the lists to find the insertion point to a minimum.

When all blocks have been inserted, you take the root, merge that list with the new root list, and re-heapify, decrementing the size of the heap by one each time, until you have a single list left. That is the final result list.

Comment: Impressive turnaround speed on posting that code! I see a couple of possible issues: 1 - your implementation seems to assume there is only one block per sub-list - at the end you would get a sorted list of the first `numlists` blocks, but i would stop there and not sort the rest of the blocks. Second, there's nothing to guarantee that the "top" blocks in the array are the ones with the smallest blocknums (which is actually a problem with my solution as well, now that I think about it).

Comment: @KBriggs: Yes, I assumed that by "block", you meant the chain hanging off a single pointer in the pointer array.

Comment: I guess I was unclear - each chain has multiple blocks in it. array[0] might contain blocks 0,4,6,8 and array[1] might contain blocks 1,2,3,5,7, in order, and each block consists of a list of already-sorted nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Excellent solution, I'll be implementing something similar.

Comment: @KBriggs: If you can, look into modifying the existing code so that each block gets added to a new entry in the array in the first place (and preferably with pointers to first and last element in that list) -- essentially, converting your array of `edge *` to an array of `edge_block`. That is likely to yield the best speedups, because you can then skip scanning the sublists altogether. Always avoid extra work, if you can :)

Comment: The particular form of this is a consequence of a parallel for loop - each thread builds its own list, with blocks coming from the natural splitting of the loop into sections of indices. What you suggest is certainly possible, just not a very natural way to approach it.

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand it you have multiple sorted lists and you want to merge them together to create a single sorted list.

A common way to do this is to create a queue of lists and continually merge pairs, adding the result back to the queue, and repeating until there is only one list left. For example:

```
listQueue = queue of lists to be merged
while listQueue.count > 1
{
    list1 = listQueue.dequeue
    list2 = listQueue.dequeue
    newList = new list
    // do standard merge here
    while (list1 != null && list2 != null)
    {
        if (list1.item <= list2.item)
        {
            newList.append(list1.item)
            list1 = list1.next
        }
        else
        {
            newList.append(list2.item)
            list2 = list2.next
        }
    }
    // clean up the stragglers, if any
    while (list1 != null)
    {
        newList.append(list1.item)
        list1 = list1.next
    }
    while (list2 != null)
    {
        newList.append(list2.item)
        list2 = list2.next
    }
    listQueue.enqueue(newList)
}
mergedList = listQueue.dequeue
```

This is an attractive option because it's simple and requires very little additional memory, and it's reasonably efficient.

There is a potentially faster way that requires a little more memory (O(log k), where k is the number of lists), and requires a bit more coding. It involves creating a min-heap that contains the first item from each list. You remove the lowest item from the heap, add it to the new list, and then take the next item from the list that the lowest item was from, and insert it into the heap.

Both of those algorithms are O(n log k) complexity, but the second is probably faster because it doesn't move data around as much. Which algorithm you want to use will depend on how large your lists are and how often you do the merge.

Comment: Interesting implementation. In my case it needs an extra step because I'm sorting at the block level rather than the node level, but it translates straightforwardly.

Comment: Actually, never mind, it works directly. I was thinking it was less efficient since I had to visit each node instead of just the block nodes, but I have to traverse the whole list anyway so it evens out.

Comment: You could certainly speed things up by aggregating the blocks (i.e. creating a structure that contains the block number and a list of individual items), sorting the blocks, and then re-constituting the lists by extracting them from the aggregate structures.

Comment: I considered that, might be my next attempt